# Cannot infer template argument 'T'

Tags: c++, templates, predicate, template-argument-deduction

I have pretty simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename Function>
int ex_count(typename list<T>::iterator v, typename list<T>::iterator v2, Function match)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(v != v2)
    {
        if(match(*v))
            count++;
        ++v;
    }
    return count;
}

template <typename T>
class ex_eq
{
    public:
    ex_eq(const T &n_target = T())
    {
        target = n_target;
    }
    bool operator() (const T &a)
    {
        return a == target;
    }
    private:
    T target;
};

int main() 
{
    list<int> v;
    list<int>::iterator iv;
    int value;
    while (cin >> value)
        v.push_back(value);
    int target = *v.begin();
    int N = ex_count(v.begin(), v.end(), ex_eq<int>(target));
    cout << "Found " << N << " instances of " << target << "\n";
}
```

I recently implemented a predicate object `Function match` into the `int ex_count()` function, but for whatever reason this breaks the code. The only error I'm getting is that the argument 'T' cannot be inferred, for `int ex_count()`, even though this was working fine using a constant instead of an object (`Function match`).

I should note that I'm not looking for advice for anything other than the question I am asking. The code is overly complicated and pointless--I'm aware, but this is not my design.

What's the issue?

Error for clarity:

```
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
int ex_count(typename list<T>::iterator v, typename list<T>::iterator v2, Function match)
```

Edit:

I've been told that it cannot be deduced because of the `::` operator, but then why is it that this version of the code only works when using the `::` operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int ex_count(typename list<T>::iterator v, typename list<T>::iterator v2, T target)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(v != v2)
    {
        if(*v == target)
            ++count;
        ++v;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    list<int> v;
    list<int>::iterator iv;
    int value;
    while (cin >> value)
        v.push_back(value);
    int target = *v.begin();
    int N = ex_count(v.begin(), v.end(), target);
    cout << "Found " << N << " instances of " << target << "\n";
}
```

This version does not use a function object, but instead just uses `target`. However, if I try to change `ex_count` arguments from `list<T>::iterator` to just `T`, I get the error:

```
note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T'
      ('std::__1::__list_iterator<int, void *>' vs. 'int')
int ex_count(T v, T v2, T target)
```

But it compiles just fine the way I have it written above.

So what causes this?

Comment: it is rather uncommon to require iterators from a specifc container. In your case you'd rather want forward iterators, no matter from what container they come from, admittedly thats not easy to express without concepts

Comment: I think the algorithm you are trying to implement already exists as [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template parameter `T` can't be deduced because of [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose **P** do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 1. The *nested-name-specifier* (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator `::`) of a type that was specified using a [qualified-id](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers):

You can specify the template argument explicitly to bypass the template argument deduction,

```
int N = ex_count<int>(v.begin(), v.end(), ex_eq<int>(target));
```

Or change the function template to specify the iterator type as the template parameter directly. (And it could be used with any iterators, including raw pointers.)

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Function>
int ex_count(Iterator v, Iterator v2, Function match)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(v != v2)
    {
        if(match(*v))
            count++;
        ++v;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**EDIT**

For

```
template <typename T>
int ex_count(typename list<T>::iterator v, typename list<T>::iterator v2, T target)
```

Template argument deduction won't be performed on non-deduced context, then `T` will be deduced only on the 3rd function argument. Given `ex_count(v.begin(), v.end(), target);` `T` will be deduece as `int`, and `v.begin()` and `v.end()` match the type `list<int>::iterator`, everything is fine.

For

```
template <typename T>
int ex_count(T v, T v2, T target)
```

There's no non-deduced context and `T` will be deduced on all the function arguments. Given `ex_count(v.begin(), v.end(), target);`, on the 1st and 2nd function arguments `T` will be deduced as `list<int>::iterator`, on the 3rd one it'll be deduced as `int`, they are conflicting.

If you seperate the template parameters then it'll be fine.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename T>
int ex_count(Iterator v, Iterator v2, T target)
```

Comment: I made an edit to my post, if you could take a look that'd be wonderful. Otherwise, you solved my main issue.